# Указатели и объекты - ошибка в данных

Tags: c++, сеть

```
#include "Array.h"

Array::Array(int n) {
  size = n;
  array = new int[n];
}

Array::Array() {

  size = 0;
  array = 0;
}

void Array::input() {

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cin >> array[i];
}

void Array::show() {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << array[i] << " ";
}

Array Array::connect(Array array2) {

  bool label = false;
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    label = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < array2.size; j++) {
      if (array[i] == array2.array[j]) {
        label = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (label == false)
      count++;
  }
  Array array3(size + count);

  count = size;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array3.array[i] = array[i];

  for (int i = 0; i < array2.size; i++) {
    label = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (array2.array[i] == array3.array[j]) {
        label = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (label == false) {
      array3.array[count] = array2.array[i];
      count++;
    }
  }
  return array3;
}

Array::~Array() { delete[] array; }

#include "Array.h"

int main() {
  int n;

  cout << "Input Array_1 size: ";
  cin >> n;
  Array array1(n);
  cout << "Input Array_1 data: ";
  array1.input();

  cout << "Input Array_2 size: ";
  cin >> n;
  Array array2(n);
  cout << "Input Array_2 data: ";
  array2.input();

  Array array3 = array1.connect(array2);
  cout << "Result: " << endl;

  array1.show();
  cout << endl;

  array2.show();
  cout << endl;

  array3.show();
  cout << endl;

  array1.~Array();
  array2.~Array();
  array3.~Array();

  return 0;
}
```

Почему до функции `connect` все данные в объектах нормальные, а после неё - искажаются? Это весёлая игра указателей?

Comment: Также очевидно, что в коде не соблюдено **Правило Трех**. А оно критично например в функции `connect`, возвращающей объект по значению.

Comment: инициализация есть, код плохо скопипастился. Насчет правила трёх не в курсе, только начал постигать ООП)

Answer (score 5):

Если вы в своем классе занимаетесь ручным управлением ресурсами (например, динамической памятью), то вам также следует соблюдать Правило Трех: не забывать реализовывать корректные *конструктор копирования*, *копирующий оператор присваивания* и *деструктор*.

(В современном С++ это правило трансформировалось в Правило Пяти, т.е. добавились перемещающий конструктор и перемещающий оператор присваивания. Но это опционально.)

В вашем конкретном случае из-за отсутствия правильно реализованного конструктора копирования невозможна ни корректная передача параметра в метод `connect`, ни корректное возвращение результата из этого метода.

(Почему передача параметра в метод `connect` делается по значению - отдельный вопрос.)

Также стоит заметить, что непонятно зачем сделанные явные вызовы деструкторов ваших объектов в конце функции `main` приведут к неопределенному поведению позже, когда эти же деструкторы будут вызваны еще раз автоматически.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array::Array(int n)
{
    array = new int[n];
}
```

почему в этом конструкторе size не инициализировано? Все уже работать будет не правильно.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) array3.array[i] = array[i];
```

тут могут быть разные размеры массивов, и ниже по коду тоже.

Comment: Алгоритм функции connect правильный, в нём ошибок нет. Вся соль в том, что функция не возвращает тот array3 , который мы в ходе функции синтезируем. и изменяет каким-то образом array2 хотя мы в нём ничего не изменяем в функции.